# cannot delete a deploy file in artifactory

Tags: artifactory

I deployed the file name efw immediately instead of efw.zip as the deploy file, and I can't delete efw. Can you help to find the solution?

[image]

```
2022-08-23 08:50:48,791 [http-nio-8081-exec-16] [ERROR] (o.a.r.c.e.m.GlobalExceptionMapper:48) - Expected a file but found a folder, at: auto-trashcan:aflac-hzn-RestrictedLib-repo/efw/efw
org.artifactory.api.repo.exception.FileExpectedException: Expected a file but found a folder, at: auto-trashcan:aflac-hzn-RestrictedLib-repo/efw/efw
    at org.artifactory.storage.db.fs.model.DbMutableFileProvider.getMutableFile(DbMutableFileProvider.java:56)
    at org.artifactory.repo.db.DbStoringRepoMixin.getMutableFile(DbStoringRepoMixin.java:684)
    at org.artifactory.repo.db.DbLocalRepo.getMutableFile(DbLocalRepo.java:249)
    at org.artifactory.repo.service.mover.BaseRepoPathMover.createMoveCopyContext(BaseRepoPathMover.java:522)
    at org.artifactory.repo.service.mover.BaseRepoPathMover.moveFile(BaseRepoPathMover.java:506)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there's already a folder available under the trash can conflicting with the deletion task being performed. If it's fine with you, try to clear the "aflac-hzn-RestrictedLib-repo/efw/efw" from trash-can first and then attempt to delete it from the respository.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

can I konw the method of  clear the "aflac-hzn-RestrictedLib-repo/efw/efw" from trash-can?

Thanks